# Dimple.js - how to center align legend and create a box around the elements

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

Is there a way to center align the legend and draw a box around the legend elements in dimple.js?
I am trying to achieve the below. Also I want to reduce space between the legend elements.
Currently I am using the following command to render the legend.

```
var legends = chart.addLegend(30, 270, 700, 20, "left");
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post more of your code?

Comment: Basically addLegend method is all that you [need](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.chart#addLegend)
If you want more control over the legend, you'll need to use some d3.

Comment: To reduce space between legend elements, did you try using a smaller "width" parameter (3rd argument fo the method)?  `this.addLegend = function (x, y, width, height, horizontalAlign, series) { ...}`. Look at dimple.js full source code with comments: http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.3.0.js